# javascript image slider that gathers images from directory

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, slider

I'm looking for an image slider tutorial, well i know how to make one but I am after a solution that is able to make the slider search a specified directory for the files to scroll through.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just need to develop a backend script to scan the requested directory and return the images. Could be a .php script, could be something else. Image array can be delivered on page load or asynchronous via an Ajax request.

Comment: where would i start with the php script?